# Android urlConnection.getInputStream vs url.getContent

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I am downloading large files from a remote server using my Android app. My question is, which method should I use to provide better performance?

`InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();`

**Or**

`InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();`

Answer (score 0):

It won't make the slightest difference. Your request will be either network-bound or, less probably, server-bound.